# error replaceAll() java method

Tags: java, regex

I have these tags in my textarea

> `<gras>.....</gras>`

And I'm trying to replace them using the **replaceAll()** String method

> `text.replaceAll("<gras>", "<b>");`
>
> `text.replaceAll("</gras>", "</b>");`

But, this regex code doesn't work. Any help please ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replace? Just the open tag? Open and close tags? Open and close tags and all the content within?

Comment: "doesn't work" is pretty vague. What happens? And why are you using `replaceAll` (which uses regular expressions) instead of `replace`?

Comment: Try to escape the operands with `\<` and `\>`.

Comment: Are you assigning the return value to anything?  Remember that Strings are immutable in Java, and it returns the modified value instead of modifying the argument in-place.

Comment: Can you show your full code ?

Comment: @bashophil: No, that's not the problem.  Angle brackets have no special meaning in Java (or in most other regex flavors, for that matter).

Comment: @bashophil If that was the problem (which it isn't) your suggestion wouldn't be useful because it would be `\\<` and `\\>`

Answer (score 5):

You forgot a very important concept;

.
**Change** `text.replaceAll("<gras>", "Bold!");`

To

```
text = text.replaceAll("<gras>", "Bold!");
```

Assign `text = some Function`, as text.replace() is creating a new String object and not referencing it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Strings don't replace.  Strings construct new Strings with the replacement values.

Also, if you are dealing with XML, regex is the wrong tool.  That doesn't mean it can't work, and it might be useful in some limited examples, but it shouldn't be the first tool to use.  Much like a hammer shouldn't be the first tool to use when installing a screw.